# language specific pages are confused while creating a new portal from "Portal template" in bilingual portals

Tags: multilingual, portal, dotnetnuke

While creating a new Portal (dnn 5.6.1) from "portal template" which is created from a bilingual portal(en and tr), all pages(both en and tr) are created in one language. if I activated the second language creates another set of pages for both en and tr pages.
I tried creating a portal template while the second language is disabled but result is same.
do you have any idea to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that, at time of writing, this is an outstanding issue that can't be resolved directly through the UI (I say that because it sounds like you tried every reasonable measure).

If that is the case, your best bet would probably be to edit the generated portal template XML file and remove the elements that represent the second languages pages prior to importing to your target dnn instance. Then you could enable the second language and it would replicate the first language's pages and you could re-localize them. (Hopefully you don't have a ton of pages!).

Alternatively, you could potentially export page level templates for the second language and import them after you've done the import of the portal in the first language. If you take this path, and you have a lot of pages, you may export individually but "bulk import" them by placing them in the /Install/Template folder and hitting the /Install/Install.aspx?mode=installresources URL.

Answer (score 0):

DNN 5.6.1 and i believe also DNN6 has serious issues with exporting/importing multilingual portals. From what i read, the multilingual issue is overcome in DNN 7 which is a major update.

One way to work with legacy multilingual DNN sites is this (far from ideal):

- The template which is going to be exported must be in only one language. You may not press the "enable content localization". This is the moment after which export/import becomes very messy.
- You export the single language template (this you must keep as the backup point)
- Now you import your template.
- Then you enable other languages & content localization button (wait till pages are created)
- Now you enter the content into the second language pages.
- No backups can be created, so you can only backup the content you have entered in the second language, manually..

In any case i recommend you start fresh with DNN7 or a different CMS altogether (WP, Drupal, Joomla...).